# How to display regular posts & custom post types that fall under a category using just the generic category template?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

1) My site has posts, and 2 custom post types (news & essays)
2) They all share normal categories like sports & health (no custom taxanomy involved)
3) Using the generic category.php template, how do I make it so this template handles all categories while displaying all content falling under it regardless of content post type.

Or simply, I would like the generic category.php template to handle all category displays but should include custom post types as well.

This may be a stupid question but have returned to Wordpress after a long hiatus and am finding the default wordpress themes hard to understand to do this. Just confused and frustrated right now.

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function - your amigo for altering the main/default query. You want to call global `$wp_query` beforehand to alter the original query instead of replacing it.

Something like this should do the trick for you. Put the first four lines in your `category.php` right before the main loop begins:

```
// Modify the default loop, include custom post types
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'any' ) );
query_posts( $args );

// The beginning of the loop looks like this:
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

If you want to be more selective in displaying your post types you can provide an array with the desired post types instead of generic `'post_type'=>'any'`:

```
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => array('post','news','essays') ) );
```

*And welcome back to the WordPress universe and WPSE community.

I'm sure the frustration will be gone soon ;)*

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much Maugly. Can't show enough appreciation ... twas so frustrating. Love ya... as a platonic admirer, of course :p

Answer (score 3):

At first I used Maugly's solution but then i found this one in wordpress codex :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type' );
/**
 * @param WP_Query $query
 * @return WP_Query
 */
function add_my_custom_post_type( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_main_query()) 
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'any_custom_type' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

Hope it will help someone .. maybe it's not the cleanest but a little bit cleaner than Maugly's solution ..

Answer (score 0):

► Here is my version of the @Kower's suggestion. Solves a couple of problems in admin.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type');

/**
 * @param WP_Query $query
 * @return WP_Query
 */
function add_my_custom_post_type($query) {
    if(
        empty($query->query['post_type'])
        or $query->query['post_type'] === 'post'
    ){
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'my_custom_type'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Also possible: `$query->set('post_type', 'any');`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to this, in reference to @tivnet's answer. (*I would have liked to have left a comment but my rep is not high enough*)

I found the solutions worked, however they presumably had the unintended consequence of affecting the admin area as well, meaning that visiting the posts in the wp-admin (wp-admin/edit.php) would also show all pages and all custom post types in the generic post list. Confusing for other users perhaps? However, adding:

```
and !is_admin()
```

within the if() statement appears to solve this issue while keeping the pre_get_posts amend on the front end.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type');

/**
 * @param WP_Query $query
 * @return WP_Query
 */
function add_my_custom_post_type($query) {
    if(
        empty($query->query['post_type'])
        or $query->query['post_type'] === 'post'
        and !is_admin()
    ){
        $query->set('post_type', 'any');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To include a custom post type in the regular loop (ie. posts page) just add the following code to index.php before `if ( have_posts() ) :`

```
$args = array(
'post_type'   => array('post', 'custom_post_type'),
'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$new_post_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

then modify the following two lines:

`if ( have_posts() ) :` change it to `if ( $new_post_loop -> have_posts() ) :`

and

`while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` to `while ( $new_post_loop -> have_posts() ) : $new_post_loop -> the_post();`

This solution avoids the problem of having the custom post type listed in the all posts screen on the backend, which using add_action('pre_get_posts') produces ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) 
{
 if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) 
 {
   $query->set( 'post_type', array(
  'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'your-custom-post-type-here'
   ));
  return $query;
}
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```