# How can I make my custom posts appear in their assigned category url?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I am trying to solve this problem:

I created new custom post types. When I create a post and assign a category (lets say category-1) to it, and when I try to visit the category-1 url, it appears "There has been an error."

I tried solving the issue based on the Michal Mau post ([How to display regular posts & custom post types that fall under a category using just the generic category template?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27104/how-to-display-regular-posts-custom-post-types-that-fall-under-a-category-usin)).

My edited code after adding Michal Mau suggestion looks like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'any' ) );
query_posts( $args );

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post-holder'); ?>>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                echo '<figure class="featured-thumbnail"><span class="img-wrap"><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">';
                echo the_post_thumbnail();
                echo '</a></span></figure>';
                }
            ?>
```

**The problem wasn't solved. I don't know if there is a mistake pasting the code or any other mistake.**

Comment: This may sound stupid. I always people click save button **a few times** on permalink structure setting first if they have problems with cpt.

Answer (score 1):

The query_posts solution is not reccomended (see [you don't know query](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-portland-2011)). You should use [pre_get_posts hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) instead. See:

```
function my_extend_category_by_custom_post_type( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'any' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_extend_category_by_custom_post_type' );
```

PS: this should go into your functions.php if (custom post type is set from there) or, preferably, from [site specific plugin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/).